# Vuejs - Retrieve input value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple input to get user's email and I want to send an http post request to save the email in the DB.

This is the "form":

```
<input v-model="email" id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Inser your email...">
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Save" v-if="isValidEmail" v-on:click="save(email)">
```

This is the Vue script:

```
    new Vue({
        el: '#body',
        data: {
            email: ''
        },
        computed: {
            isValidEmail: function(){
                var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
                return re.test(this.email);
            }
        },
        methods: {
            save: function(passedEmail){

                this.$http.post('action.php', passedEmail, function (data) {

                    swal({
                        title: data.title,
                        text: data.text,
                        timer: 5000,
                        type: data.type,
                        showConfirmButton: true
                    });

                }).error(function (data) {
                    swal({
                        title: 'Errore',
                        text: 'Si è verificato un errore sconosciuto.',
                        timer: 5000,
                        type: 'error',
                        showConfirmButton: true
                    });

                });
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I get the email value in my `action.php` file?
I tried a simple `print_r($_POST)` but it is empty while `passedEmail` contains the actual email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved.

The problem is that Vue ( at least in my case ) send the data in the Request's playload so to retrieve the input you need to use:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an object as data,

```
this.$http.post('action.php', {email: passedEmail}, function (data) {
  ...
})
```